# How to determine object is detected or not with opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, opencv3.1

I am using `ORB` feature matching algorithm to detect the object . I have followed [this Sample](https://github.com/ykenichi/ObjectFinder) . I am  able to detect the object which is used as template `Mat`.

[image]

So i have the `Rect` of the object in the current Frame `Mat` . How can i make a decision whether object is detected or not ?

If you need to see the algorithm you can check the link above . The code is quite big to post here. But i am posting the final drawing of points below .

```
        Imgproc.line(rgb, new Point(sceneCorners.get(0, 0)), new Point(sceneCorners.get(1, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Imgproc.line(rgb, new Point(sceneCorners.get(1, 0)), new Point(sceneCorners.get(2, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Imgproc.line(rgb, new Point(sceneCorners.get(2, 0)), new Point(sceneCorners.get(3, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
        Imgproc.line(rgb, new Point(sceneCorners.get(3, 0)), new Point(sceneCorners.get(0, 0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
```

i.e what i have is a `Rect` of the object in the `Mat` Frame. How can i decide if object was found or not . My question is quite similar to [This one](http://answers.opencv.org/question/133505/how-to-count-image-similarity/).

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505299/finding-if-two-images-are-similar/42515173#42515173). You can basically check the similarity between the two images.

Comment: Thx for the link. Too much to grab for me cause i am very new to OpenCV.  Can't i make an accurate assumption on basis of Points , inlier and outliers?

Comment: Also do i have to perform all four checks to get accurate result? Although I do not understand check 2 and check 4. In my case i have a single template as png in assets . And i need to detect this from camera frame . Thats it only one template . Which check should i prefer ?

Comment: please post the exact requirement. Do you want to detect only one image or they are of different type? Will the original image and the test image vary in terms of orientation, scale, intensity etc?

Comment: Template image will be a single image lets say (300X300) png it will be same for whole app. It contains an object (lets say a mobile phone) And i need to find this template object in the camera frame . if object not found -> Camera will keep looking for it.  If found i need to proceed to next screen . This is the requirement @janu777

Comment: @Diazdiaz You just need to perform one of the four checks. If the image isn't rotated in the captured image, then I would still suggest using template matching because this seems to be a bit too much work

Comment: I have tried template matching samples too but they did not work . This is a the only sample i found working in my case. For your suggested code in link i do not understand `homography_mat`. There should be two argument first object from camera frame and second is template mat . What is `homography_mat`?

Comment: Well Bundle of Thx @RickM. . You have been a great help . Will get back if i face any other issues .

Comment: Glad I could help!